# Change underline Text presets in Sketch

Tags: text, sketch-app, character

Is there any way to change underline presets at Sketch?
I'm working with symbols, and I need a text with an underline, but only text, without objects.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by changing the underline preset?  Are you simply trying to underline text? Have you checked out the documentation on the Sketch website [here](https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/text/text-inspector/)?  Can you please edit your question, and give more details as it's quite unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm trying to change underline options. Like distance between the text and stroke, the stroke weight, color... 
Like we do in some other programs (you can see below the print of idd.)
Is it that possible in Sketch?
Thank you
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIEOI.png

Answer (score 3):

For text underlining, you can have:

1. No underline
2. Single underline
3. Double underline

[image]

It turns out there isn't any more granularity than that.

To get something like your screenshot, your best bet is to create a rectangle and position it under the text how you'd like. But really, that's not a sane solution for tons of text